# When I watch a video online the screen turns off after a few minutes

Tags: video, google-chrome, lock-screen

in some sites when I watch a movie in a browser and I don't touch the computer the screen turns off. In other sites like Youtube I don't have that problem.
I tried using caffeine but I don't like the idea of having to manually enable and disable it every time I watch a video. I also tried other methods that I found on the internet but nothing worked. 
any suggestions?
I'm using chrome and running ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Could you  give an example of a video that makes you(r screen) fall asleep? need to look into the processes. See if we can get anything usefull out of it.

Comment: More specifically can you provide a link to one or more videos that will not inhibit the screensaver (that's the proper lingo for "preventing the screen from falling asleep)? I suspect they're Flash videos. Can you confirm or deny that?

Comment: FWIW, I find it happens in Totem as well as with Flash videos. http://askubuntu.com/questions/778882/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-my-screen-lock-settings-during-video-playback

Comment: I would suggest "caffeine". It keeps your computer awake http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/install-caffeine-indicator-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE 2017/08/23:**  Changed script to one that doesn't send keystrokes but disables `dpms` and the screensaver temporarily while a video is playing full screen.

*This only works with applications running full screen, not maximized.*

---

First install `xdotool`:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

then I created a `scripts` folder in my home folder that I could drop any scripts into that I wanted to keep:

```
mkdir -p ~/scripts
```

then I created a file called `check_full.bsh` in my `~/scripts` folder and added the following content to it:

*Since my screensaver is set for 20 minutes, I set the sleep timer in the script to 10 minutes (600 seconds).  You can change this based on your screensaver settings.*

```
#!/bin/bash

#Get DPMS settings
dpms_set=$(xset -q | awk '/DPMS is/ {print $NF}')

#Get screensaver type and command
scrnsvr=$(ps -ef | awk '/screensav/ {print $8}' | grep -v awk)
scrnsvrcmd=$(ps -ef | awk '/screensav/ {print substr($0,index($0,$8))}' | grep -v awk)

#Sleep Timer in seconds.
SL=600

while true;
do
result=()
#Get all window geometries
all=($(xdotool search --name - | while read win; do xdotool getwindowgeometry $win | awk '/Geometry/ {print $2}'; done))

#Get all screen resolutions detected and build array.
SCREENS=($(xrandr | awk '/\*/ {print $1}'))

SCRN=" ${SCREENS[*]} "

#Get result of all windows and match

for item in ${all[@]}; do if [[ $SCRN =~ " $item " ]] ; then result+=($item); fi; done

#If a result exists disable power management and screensaver
if [[ ${result[@]} ]]; then
    ps -ef | grep $scrnsvr | grep -v grep >/dev/null
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then 
    kill $(ps -ef | grep $scrnsvr | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
    fi
    if [[ $dpms_set == "Enabled" ]];then
    xset -dpms
    fi
else    
    ps -ef | grep $scrnsvr | grep -v grep >/dev/null
    if [[ $? == 1 ]]; then
    ${scrnsvrcmd} &
    fi
    if [[ $dpms_set != "Disabled" ]];then
        xset dpms
        fi
fi
result=()
sleep $SL
done
```

make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/scripts/check_full.bsh
```

For some reason, a cron job would not run this correctly.  So I added an entry to my startup to call this script.    In the `~/.config/autostart/` folder, I created a file called `Check_full.desktop` with the following content:

*I like to have delays added to startup as they usually load better.*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Check_Full
Comment=Prevent screensaver from activating when full screen video is playing
Exec=bash -c 'sleep 5 && /home/<username>/scripts/check_full.bsh'
```

change above Exec line to match your home folder.

Set proper permissions to the file:

```
chmod 664 ~/.config/autostart/Check_full.desktop
```

After logging out and back in, `check_full.bsh` is now running and checking every 10 minutes if active application is full screen.  If not, screensaver / lock screen launch at normal times.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you so much! It worked. Couldn't fix it without you

Comment: @p3pc1styl3 You're very welcome!  Please check the check mark next to my answer showing that it helped you and it can help others looking for the same thing.  I came up with this because although there are good solutions out there, none of them allowed me to run whatever player I wanted to to watch videos, so I came up with this script to detect anything in full screen mode.  Figured that just made it easier.  Glad it is helping you!  =)

Comment: Please don't make a ton of edits to your answer over time, Terrance.  Only make updates when there's something major to change, a ton of minor edits usually is not a good thing.

Comment: @ThomasWard I understand.  I didn't like the old answer I had and I dumped that one.   I didn't think there were a ton of minor edits anyway.

Comment: @Terrance Might want to look at [the revision history of your answer here](https://askubuntu.com/posts/778817/revisions) then and see how many small revisions you've made over time.

Comment: @ThomasWard Yeah, I was just looking at that.  The majority of them were when I first wrote it and kept changing the answer within the first 3 days.  The rest were things coming to mind over the year and a half.

Comment: Is there any way to adapt this for a certain application?

Comment: @GabrielSandoval I guess you could by adding in a line after the `for item in...` line that was a check for your application.  The line would look like `result=$(ps -ef | grep <appname> | grep -v grep)` .   What that line would do is give a value to `result`.  In the script if there is no full screen application the value of `result` is blank.

Comment: @GabrielSandoval But adding that line will actually cause the script to no longer work with full screen apps, unless you add it as a check instead like `if [[ ! ${result[@]} ]];  then result=$(ps -ef | grep <appname> | grep -v grep); fi`

Answer (score 5):

Youtube doesn't have that problem because it uses HTML5 player. The sites you're having the problem with are using Flash Player instead. It is [a bug in Adobe Flashplayer](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=96792&sid=c81fcd29e960b722c17682964619f997#p203645), which, in short, is that it never notifies WM that it ran into fullscreen. You may have heard though that Adobe Flash is a buggy app in general, so one workaround is to disable it, and use only sites with HTML5 video.

As you mentioned caffeine, you probably have searched for a solution already. Another thing you could do is to [disable «power saving» completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61291/how-to-permanently-disable-monitor-power-saver-using-the-command-line), i.e. to force the screen to never turn off.