# How can I configure my x-server, that gamepad input prevents screen locking?

Tags: screensaver, joystick

The problem is, that if I play with my gamepad (on zsnes which by the way should not matter), I get interrupted by the screenlock after some time, because the input in not coming from the mouse or keyboard.

Why is this the case? And what can I do about it?

Comment: Are you running in full screen mode when you play zsnes?

Comment: The only reason why I ask that, is that I found that either you can disable the screen saver for the time being, or I wrote a script that will prevent the screen saver from starting when an application or video are in full screen mode (you might want to press the F7 key while in the application to make sure nothing happens, the script uses that keystroke):  http://askubuntu.com/a/778817/231142