# How to prevent XScreenSaver to load while playing videos on browsers (ARM)?

Tags: screensaver, xscreensaver, gnome-screensaver

According to the [XScreenSaver wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XScreenSaver), the app should automatically recognize when browsers are playing videos, but it doesn't for me.

I'm running Ubuntu 23.04 over ARM (RPi4), and the app loads while on Firefox and Brave Browser are running Youtube videos.

The screensaver doesn't load while I'm running videos on VLC, though.

Any alternative recommendations are welcome.

Comment: I wrote a script here https://askubuntu.com/a/778817/231142 that will turn off the screensaver when it sees something full screen.  In the comment section I was helping someone out with the possibility to have it see if a specific app is running.  Just a thought.

Comment: @petep Such option doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks for sharing! I hope to find a more straightforward solution though in which any web5 video (regardless of fullscreen or not) will prevent xscreensaver to lad.